# Is it possible to implement in C++/CLR an abstract class declared in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, clr

Say I have a C# project that defines the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    public abstract void DoIt(string param);
}
```

Can I then implement it in C++/CLR as

```
public ref class MyDerivedClass : public MyAbstractClass
{
    public:
        void DoIt(String^ param)
        {

        }

};
```

If the answer is `NO, You can't do that`, is it possible to do it with an interface?

Comment: Surely you didn't mean `void void`.  More than one return type is not legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, C++/CLI managed types can inherit from C# classes and implement C# interfaces, including overloading virtual methods.  That's the whole point of the common type system.

If it isn't working for you, even after paying careful attention to the compiler errors, ask a new question showing specific code that is failing and the exact compiler error messages.

Answer (score 0):

C++/CLI compilers won't accept to process syntax and expressive grammar from other languages. So to get the C# code to work with them, code **conversion** is needed. This conversion produces symbols (i.e exported functions, classes, data etc) compiled from their own compilers that can be fed into those of C++. To build such symbols, target platforms or machines are also taken into account. There are several tools and libs that help one to bridge the gap between languages. Yet porting the produced resources among systems (Windows vs Mac vs Linux etc) will not be as smooth as one may wish especially when the original code-base is pretty large in size.